# How can I use anchor links pointing within an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, anchor

I have a html document loaded in an iframe on a website.
The document has a table of contents and clicking on any of the links jumps to the appropriate part of the document.
Navigation is supposed to work from a sidebar that is specified by a separate XML.

Adding a link to said XML displays the HTML in the iframe:
`href="source_folder/file.html"`

Issue is, when I try to add a link to a specific section, like `href="source_folder/file.html#_Toc0123"` it just jumps back to the top of the HTML.

In the usual use-case, the sections are all separate HTML files, and get linked in the corresponding XML. Issue being I don't want to go through the hassle of separating multiple large files into individual HTMLs.

Any idea on what I'm missing? Or is this simply not possible?
(I didn't build the original site, but if there is an attribute that governs it, feel free to let me know where to look for it)

Thanks!

Comment: Try adding a `target` attribute to the link, with the same value as the iframe's `name` attribute(or `id` attribute, i dont use iframe for ages)

Comment: Thanks! I ended up not having to use those, the anchor tags were sufficient. For some reason it seems to depend on the conversion. If I converted it to a filtered HTML from word, external references didn't work. Did a conversion using python and now they do. Didn't bother to check for the differences, but it seems to work now.